# ActiveAdmin filter exclude results by input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, activeadmin

I have ActiveAdmin's filter to filter results by user's email and return the results only for specific user:

```
  filter :user, :collection => proc { User.all.map { |i| [ i.to_s, i.id ] } }
```

Now I want to add option to exclude specific user from results.

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a search method and scope to the related model:

```
  search_methods :user_exclude_eq
  scope :user_exclude_eq,  lambda {|user| where('user_id != ?', user)}
```

And to the controller:

```
  filter :user_exclude, :as => :select, :collection => proc { User.all.map { |i| [ i.to_s, i.id ] } }
```